# Stopping malicious Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, security

I am using Xml http for the first time and I need to stop malicious Ajax requests through JavaScript injection. How would I go about only allowing the website make requests while not giving the user the power to make requests through the console. Would I do this by generating a key through php and using that to make a request, that changes after every request, and if that is the case how would I generate such a key.

Please tell me if I need to make anything clearer.

P.S. when using http to a php file does it matter whether I use GET or POST for security?

Comment: You can't do anything about the malicious requests. If your server is open to access then anyone can send it anything. Your token idea is a good start, but your server needs to ensure that any request received with that token only performs an action that the owner of that token is permitted to perform. You might do well to browse the pages of [security.se]

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular thanks for your response. Would I have to save every token in a sql database which has each token and the permission of that request or is there another way?

Comment: The server will need to know what permissions are associated with each token. There are a dozen ways you could track that information (or more than a dozen!). Implementing security is a big job, best done from the start. This is why many people use frameworks like Laravel that has all this built in.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular alright thank you I’ll look into that